# returning different types from a java method

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

Let's say I've a java base class:

```
class base {
    public Class<? extends base> type;
    // ...
}
```

`type` stores the classtype of classes which inherit from `base`

There's another class which stores `base` objects in a container, it also has a `get` method which returns objects stored in that container:

```
class container {
    private Vector<base> v;
    //...
    public <something here> get(int i){
        base b=v.get(i);
        return b.type.cast(b);
    }
```

How do I implement such a function(`container.get`), which casts the object to it's correct type before returning it?
It would be nice to be able to program in a cascading style:

```
JSONObject o;
//...
o.get("nestedObject").get("array").get(3);
```

Comment: do you need to return from container.get any type that extends from base?

Comment: Yes //10 more characters

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can use generic with restricting it to be extending from base <T extends base>, is that what you mean ?

Comment: I tried `public <T extends base> T get()`, and it didn't work, intellij is saying I need to cast the return type to `T`. I'm new to java, is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: try this and let me know if it works to post as correct answer -  public Class<? extends base> get(int i) {
            base b = v.get(i);
            return b.type;
        }

Comment: @msoliman the questioner wants his method to return an object, not a `Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding what a "cast" is in Java.  Except for casts that involve primitive types (such as casting an `int` to a `float`), casts don't change objects at all.

One of your instance variables is

```
private Vector<Base> v;
```

(Please use the Java convention and start class names with upper-case letters.  I've changed `base` to `Base` to set a good example.)

The objects that you put in this vector can be of type `Base` *or any subclass of* `Base`.  The type of the object is fixed when the object is constructed.  Suppose `Base` has three subclasses, `Child1`, `Child2`, and `Child3`.  Those objects can be construted with `new Child1(...)`, `new Child2(...)`, `new Child3(...)`.  As soon as you say `new Child1(...)`, you have an object whose type is `Child1`, and you can't do anything to change that.  But since a `Child1` is a `Base`, you can use your `Child1` anywhere you can use a `Base`, such as putting it into your vector `v`.

Casting just causes the compiler to look at a variable differently.  Suppose you say

```
Base x = v.get(i);
```

`x` (if not null) will be a `Base` or some object of a subclass.  The type of `x` will be whatever you used to construct the object.  Now if you say

```
Child1 y = (Child1)x;
```

If `x` is a `Child1`, `y` will be a reference to the same object as `x`.  But the compiler will know that `y` is a `Child1`, and you can access new methods that are defined in a `Child1`.  (If `x` isn't a `Child1`, you get an exception.)  But it's important to note that a cast does not create a new object and it does not change the type of anything.  It just tells the compiler to look at a variable or expression in a different way.

Given this, you cannot gain anything by trying to write a method that returns a "variable" type.  You may as well just write

```
public Base get(int i){
    return v.get(i);
}
```

The object that it returns could be a `Base`, `Child1`, `Child2`, etc.; it will be the same type as the object was when you put it into the vector.  When you call `get`, if you are expecting the result to be a `Child1`, you can say

```
Child1 child = (Child1)container.get(n);
```

which will throw an exception if the object isn't a `child1`.  Or you can use `instanceof` to check yourself:

```
Base child = container.get(n);
if (child instanceof Child1) {
    ...
}
```

If this isn't good enough, you'll need to explain more clearly what you want to accomplish and why this won't work.

**MORE:** After reading your edit, that says you want to do something like this:

```
JSONObject o;
//...
o.get("nestedObject").get("array").get(3);
```

You don't need any casting to accomplish this.  What you need is an abstract `JSONValue` base type that represents any kind of value that can be returned from a JSON parser.  The subclasses would be things like "object", "array", and whatever scalar types you need (integer, string, etc.).  `get` would return `JSONValue`.  In actuality, it will return an object of one of the other types, but all the compiler needs to know is that it returns `JSONValue`.

Now a `JSONValue` will need two `get` methods, one that takes a `String` and one that takes an `int` or `Integer`.  These will be polymorphic methods.  Say `v` is a `JSONValue` and you say `v.get("array")`: the method it actually calls may be different based on the actual type of `v`.  So if `v` is your "object" type, it will call the method you've defined for the object type; if `v` is an integer type, it will call the method defined for the integer type, and so on.  What you want is for the `get` method that takes a `String` to look up the field for the JSON "object" type, and throw an exception for everything else.  Similarly, for the `get` method that takes an integer parameter, the method for the JSON "array" type will look up a list or something, and the method for every other subclass of `JSONValue` will throw an exception.  No "casting" is needed for this.  Casting is a compile-time concept.  At all points, the compiler will know only that it's working with a `JSONValue`.  But at run time, the object's actual type is used to determine which method to call, so the compiler doesn't need to know anything more.

This is a basic concept that all Java programmers need to know (also Javascript, Python, and pretty much every other language these days, although polymorphism is handled differently in interpreted languages like Javascript and Python).  The tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html covers this and related concepts.  There may be better Java tutorials on "polymorphism" out there also.

Comment: Yes this will work, this is what I'm doing right now but it results in `if-else` chains of length 6! This code is being duplicated a lot(for every data entry in the json file). What I want is to refactor it out somehow, preferably including it in  the library itself.

Comment: You probably shouldn't need that much `if-else`.  Perhaps if you post an example of the code that uses the big `if-else` chain, we might be able to come up with a better solution.  It seems likely that you're trying to solve the problem in the wrong place.  That is, your question is about how to write the library, but it _should_ be about how to write the code that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

> `type` stores the classtype of classes which inherit from base

This is equivalent to `this.getClass()`.

> How do I implement such a function(container.get), which casts the object to it's correct type before returning it?

Not possible in theory. People will create more subclasses and put it in the container, after the code is compiled and shipped. That's the purpose of have a base class -- so that the other part of your codebase only has to work with a single interface/concept.

So basically what you want to write is just some generic container code.

```
interface Container<T extends Base> {
    public T get(int i);
}
```

But the **real question** was How can the container accommodates a set of **known** subclasses? Just use different method names. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java) does it.

```
public class Container {
    public Base get(int i) { ... }
    public SubType1 getAsSubType1(int i) { ... }
    public SubType2 getAsSubType2(int i) { ... }
}
```

And you can add custom cast methods to `Base` too.

Comment: Only if he wants a homogeneous container.  But I don't see that in the question.

Comment: `Vector<base>`? Everything in the container should be a subclass of `base`, right? @ajb

Comment: But the objects in a container could be different subclasses of `Base`.  There's not much point in making this a generic container if the objects could be all different subclasses of `Base`--you'd just be using `Container<Base>` every time you use the container.

Comment: As I said in my comment to the answer by `Thihara`, this code belongs to a json parser library, and I've implemented all the basic json types as classes inheriting from the base class. So I don't want anyone to inherit from `base`. What could be an elegent solution to this problem? I don't want to have to do 15 equality checks and typecasts whenever I have to use this code.

Comment: @saga Maybe if you edit your question and show us what you'd _like_ the code that uses the library to look like, we can figure out whether it's feasible.  (My guess is that it won't be, since Java is a compiled language, but maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: @ajb question edited, I know java is not javascript or python, but it's still an amazing language. I guess I'll have to use different methods as suggested by xiofeng.li

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Generics doesn't really work that way. There's no way to know the exact subtype of your object at compile time.

This `b.type.cast(b);` casting will need to be done on the result of your method `public <something here> get(int i)` wherever it's called.

If you have designed the system well you won't need to cast the object back to the exact subclass much, if at all.

Otherwise your best bet is to do a `instanceof` type check where needed.

Comment: I faced this problem while writing a json file parser. I've a base jsontype class and several other classes (like object, array, double, string...) which extend from it. json arrays are implemented as an arraylist of `jsontype`s and objects as `HashMap<String,JSONType>`. The users of this code will have to manually cast the object to use them. What could I do different to avoid this ugliness?

Comment: See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java

You want to look at `fromJson` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score -3):

I think you are referring to Generics

```
class container<GenericType> {
    private Vector<GenericType> v;
    //...
    public GenericType get(int i){
        GenericType b=v.get(i);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `GenericType` has to be `base`, then the `get` method you offered will always return a `base` object. I want the code to cast the object stored in the container to it's correct type as stored in the `type` field of `base`. `base` and it's children will be stored in container.